# Issue parsing JSON child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my JSON String

```
    "book_types": {
        "type": "1",
        "books": [
            {
                "name": "default",
                "cover": null,
                "lastUpdated": {
                    "microsecond": 114250,
                    "ctime": "Fri Aug  9 01:27:45 2013"
                },
                "cat": 0,
                "other_thumbs": [],
                "book_type": 1,
                "thumbs": [],
                "id": "8001",
                "bk_follow_uids": [],
                "desc": "default",
                "bk_update_uids": [],
                "uid": 6001,
                "no": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

which is valid. When I call `toJSON(jsonStr)`, it returns

> Object {book_types: Object}
>   book_types: Object
>   books: Array[1]

Here is toJSON function:

```
function toJSON(jobj) {
   obj = JSON && JSON.parse(jobj) || $.parseJSON(jobj);
   return(obj);
}
```

Can someone please let me know as why the `book_types` is nested in `book_types`.

I apoglize if it is trivial, but I could not figure out the reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear (at least to me). What do you mean with "the book_types is nested in book_types" ?

Comment: `toJSON` is a very misleading name for a function that decodes a JSON string ***to*** an object.

Comment: Firstly, your example is an object, not a string, so I'm confused why you need to `toJSON` it? Secondly, I don't understand the question, `book_types` is an object, hence why it's alerting as `[object Object]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because book types *is* nested in your object.

If you take a look at this smaller example:

```
{
    "book_types": {
        "type": "1"
     }
}
```

You have an object containing a member, that member is an object called `book_types` and it contains itself a member which is a string with the value `"1"`.

Just like `{}` is an object. This is how [json syntax](http://json.org/) works:

First it hits `object`:

[image]

This is the return value, an object like you see. Then inside that object it hits the string `book_types` and the value of it, is an object itself.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for the detailed explanation and thanks @dystroy fothe clarification.